# Angular bootstrap HTML processing of tab dynamic content

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Angular Bootstrap tabs.  I'd like to use them with their content loaded from an Angular Model.  However, all HTML in the content loaded fromt eh model is ignored.  i.e. if I have

```
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:"<b>Dynamic</b> content 1" },
    { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
  ];
```

The first tab's content is "**Dynamic** content 1", not "Dynamic content 1" with "Dynamic" in bold.  If the content as statically supplied in the html file, it would show correctly.

[Plunker to demonstrate the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/25Xlozcd14ykLEyHRdFT?p=preview)

Anyone know how I can force the html to be parsed properly?

Thank you,
Greg

Comment: you need to make use of `$sce` and `trustAsHtml()` to allow dynamic content.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#!/

Comment: When parsing html you may want to use ng-bind-html  --> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in the comments, you can create a function called:

```
scope.trustHtml = function(content){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml( content );
}
```

and then change your HTML to be like:

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
    <span ng-bind-html="trustHtml(tab.content)"></span>
</tab>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works.  I tried something based on the comments, and it failed so completely I threw it away, and now have no idea what I did differently. :-) Oh, well, thank you for something that works!